# HTML Elements Disappear When Resizing Window

Tags: html, css

I'm a novice coder and I'm building my first proper website. I have a column of button links down the right hand side of my page. However, they're only visible if the window is full-screen. If I use my mouse to shrink the size of the window, the buttons disappear. Is there any way that I can make the buttons stay visible if the window changes size?

Here's the HTML code:

```css
/* Scroll down to the bit that says ALL MY BUTTONS for the relevant CSS. */

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #555;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}

.row {
  max-width: 1140px;
  //margin: 0 auto;
}

header {
  background-image: url(img/joshua-earle-183442.jpg);
  background: no-repeat center center cover;
  height: 100vh;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.hero-text-box {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1140px;
  top: 5%;
  left 50%;
  font-family: 'Orbitron', 'Arial', sans-serif;
  margin-left: 15px;
  word-spacing: 15px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

h1 {
  margin-top: 0;
  color: #ef872e;
}

/****ALL MY BUTTONS***/

.quizzes {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 1730px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  top: 50%;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ef872e;
  font-family: 'Orbitron';
  padding: 10px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-color: #ef872e;
}

.calculators {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 1692px;
  top: 55%;
  color: #ef872e;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Orbitron';
  padding: 10px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-color: #ef872e;
}

.solarsystem {
  position: absolute;
  width: 230px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-left: 1612px;
  top: 60%;
  color: #ef872e;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Orbitron';
  padding: 10px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-color: #ef872e;
}

.mysteries {
  position: absolute;
  width: 240px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 60px;
  margin-left: 1602px;
  top: 65%;
  color: #ef872e;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Orbitron';
  padding: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-color: #ef872e;
}

.otherresources {
  position: absolute;
  width: 220px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: 1623px;
  top: 75%;
  color: #ef872e;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Orbitron';
  padding: 10px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-color: #ef872e;
}

.full:hover,
.full:active {
  background-color: #e97512;
  color: #fff;
  transition: background-color 0.3s;
  transition: color 0.3s;
}

.ghost:hover,
.ghost:active {
  border-color: #e97512;
  background-color: #e97512;
  color: #fff;
  transition: background-color 0.3s;
  transition: color 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendors/css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendors/css/grid.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/style.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato|Orbitron:400,500" rel="stylesheet" type=text/css>
  <title>Interactive Galaxy</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="hero-text-box">
      <h1>Explore the universe, or whatever...</h1>
    </div>

    <a class="quizzes full" href="#">Quizzes</a>
    <a class="calculators ghost" href="#">Calculators</a>
    <a class="solarsystem ghost" href="#">The Solar System</a>
    <a class="mysteries ghost" href="#">Mysteries of Space</a>
    <a class="otherresources ghost" href="#">Other Resources</a>
  </header>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I wouldn't absolutely position everything, it may be easy to start with but in the long run it will lead to a lot of layering and z-index problems.  I would look into properly positioning items and getting a better understanding of basic css and have a read up on relative vs absolute units (which is what your problem with the above code boils down to)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove all the margin-left from your links. surround all your links by a div like this:

```
        <div class="links">
            <a class="quizzes full" href="#">Quizzes</a>
            <a class="calculators ghost" href="#">Calculators</a>
            <a class="solarsystem ghost" href="#">The Solar System</a>
            <a class="mysteries ghost" href="#">Mysteries of Space</a>
            <a class="otherresources ghost" href="#">Other Resources</a>
        </div>
```

and then change the links container style like this :

```
.links {
  float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason is your `margin-left` property, simply, the window is not enough to display these many pixels. better set:

```
display: inline-block;
float: right;
```

Also, better put your buttons in the list for better view and controls in styling.

Answer (score 0):

Your `margin-left` property is defined by a set number of pixels:

```
margin-left: 1730px;
```

Even when the screen is smaller, that rule will still apply by pixel count. To make your page more responsive, change the margin to a percentage, like:

```
margin-left: 80%;               /* 80% is just an example */
```

or use @VaxoBasilidze's idea of applying `float: right;`.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simple.
You used a `top:` in `%` , so when you resize the window. css calculates the stated % according to window  current width.

so to solve this; update your `top:` to `px;` like `top: 555px;` so when you resize the window your buttons will be visible.